# Changing Word mail merge data source locations in bulk?

Tags: microsoft-word, mail-merge, bulk

I've just moved a number of Word mail merge files, and a number of Excel spreadsheets that are the data sources for the mail merges, from a Windows XP computer to a Windows 7 computer, and now all the paths for the merge sources are incorrect (used to be c:\documents and settings\user\my documents.... now c:\users\documents....). While I can correct the path of the data source in each file individually, I was hoping that there would be some way of updating the files in bulk, as there are a relatively large number of them. Word 2007 is what is being used, but the documents are all in the previous DOC format (not DOCX).

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a registry setting you can tweak as [described here:](http://www.gmayor.com/merge_labels_with_word_2007.htm)

> ### Choose the data source
>
> Word can use a wide variety of data
>   sources. The 'Select Recipients' icon
>   offers the option to type a new list,
>   to use an existing list or to select
>   from Outlook Contacts. (Outlook 2007
>   still provides the option to start the
>   merge from Outlook for even greater
>   flexibility - the procedure is
>   essentially the same as that for
>   Outlook 2003).
>
> [image]
>
> If you chose to use an existing
>   data source, by default Word 2007 will
>   try and connect to a data source in
>   the 'My Data Sources' folder. This
>   will not help much if the data source
>   is a Word or Excel document, for
>   example, in some other folder. Don't
>   be thrown by the two default entries
>   shown in the illustration below,
>   simply move to the folder that
>   contains your data file and select it.
>
> [image]
>
> There is no mechanism included by
>   which the My Data Sources folder can
>   be set to a different location;
>   however, you can set the data source
>   folder to a path on the same drive as
>   the My Documents folder by means of a
>   registry hack. The folder is defined
>   at:
>
> ```
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Common\DataServices
> ```
>
> Edit the 'MyData' sub key to the
>   required folder name (without quotes).
>   The start point for the path is My
>   Documents and the entry in the data
>   key would be a sub folder of My
>   Documents, which by default is the My
>   Data Sources sub folder. If the
>   DataServices key has no entry the
>   default setting is used. To move up to
>   My Documents enter . (a period/full
>   stop). To move up two folders enter ..
>   (two periods/full stops). Although I
>   have not tested it, the convention is
>   one period/full stop for each level,
>   so if your My Documents folder is
>   buried deeper, in theory at least you
>   should be able to add extra
>   periods/full stops to take you back to
>   the root level of the drive. I regret
>   I have not found a way to change
>   drives within this mechanism.
>
> This method allow you to move the
>   folder to a different path location.
>   e.g., here I have My Documents as a
>   sub folder of the D: drive i.e. "D:\My
>   Documents" thus the default setting
>   for the data folder would be "D:\My
>   Documents\My Data Sources" . To move
>   that data folder to "D:\My Documents"
>   you would change the default My Data
>   Sources entry for a period/full stop
>   to move up a level.
>
> [image]
>
> To move to another
>   sub folder of My Documents eg "D:\My
>   Documents\Merge" simply change the
>   default "My Data Sources" to "Merge"
>
> [image]
>
> and to move to a different branch of
>   the folder structure eg to "D:\Merge",
>   add the period/full stop to the path
>   as below:
>
> [image]

Comment: That looks like it would be handy for creating new documents, but I was looking for a way to update the data source path in *existing* documents, which this doesn't look like it does.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting a shortcut to the sources you want, inside the My Data Sources folder.  This works for me.  I have the opposite problem now, having just been "upgraded" to Office 10.  I WANT the merge to open "My Data Sources" (where all my shortcuts and directories are) but instead it sends me to a QUERIES folder somewhere in Office14.  I'm no tech wiz, but maybe this registry hack will work if I can get there and figure it out.